# What is the easiest and/or fastest way to find players?

Tags: gm-techniques, group-dynamics, social, finding-other-players

You have just arrived to a new town, you do not even know where the tavern is but an incessant need to form a group and start playing invades you.

What do you do? How to detect the ones who are the same as you or where they meet
?

Comment: Incidentally we have a [tag:finding-other-players] tag, and a question covering the basics. :) If this doesn't answer your question, you can revise it to clarify what's different in what you're looking for.

Comment: It's duplicate. I just tried to make it more 'creative'. It's basically the top question of finding-other-players tag. I just searched in incorrect tags.